# using mailto to send email with an attachment

Tags: html

How can i send an email with an attachment (either local file or a file in the intranet) using outlook 2010?

```
<a href="mailto:a@gmail.com?subject=my report&body=see attachment&attachment=c:\myfolder\myfile.txt">
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There is also a solution using EML file in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25586282/5267751 which might work if the program can run on the client instead of just a website.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible at all. There is no provision for it in the `mailto:` protocol, and it would be a gaping security hole if it were possible.

The best idea to send a file, but have the client send the E-Mail that I can think of is:

- Have the user choose a file
- Upload the file to a server
- Have the server return a random file name after upload
- Build a `mailto:` link that contains the URL to the uploaded file in the message body

Comment: In this case i could use apache commons i think.

Comment: not bad, but there will be a place on the server where all the user files are located that will need cleaning from time to time somehow. Maybe [this approach would work for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760969/php-how-to-delete-a-file-from-server-after-is-read-unlink-is-executed-befor)

Comment: Apparently Thunderbird and some other clients *did* support `?attach=...` until December 2019: https://www.nds.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/media/nds/veroeffentlichungen/2020/08/15/mailto-paper.pdf . But now it is removed, for the obvious reasons.

Comment: @jpa, relevant: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1613425#c0

Comment: What would be the security hole? Assuming the file data would have to be URI encoded

Answer (score 2):

this is not possible in "mailto" function.

please go with server side coding(C#).make sure open vs in administrative permission.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

oMsg.Subject = "emailSubject";
oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
oMsg.BCC = "emailBcc";
oMsg.To = "emailRecipient";

string body = "emailMessage";

oMsg.HTMLBody = "body";              
oMsg.Attachments.Add(Convert.ToString(@"/my_location_virtual_path/myfile.txt"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

oMsg.Display(false); //In order to displ
```

Comment: i have tried with mailto function but its not possible, so i have tried above code to achieve that.

Comment: Isn't it [problematic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) using Microsoft Office automation on a server?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using c# on the desktop, you can use [SimpleMapi](https://github.com/PandaWood/Simple-MAPI.NET). That way it will be sent using the default mail client, and the user has the option of reviewing the message before sending, just like `mailto:`.

To use it you add the [Simple-MAPI.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple-MAPI.NET/) package (it's 13Kb), and run:

```
var mapi = new SimpleMapi();
mapi.AddRecipient(null, address, false);
mapi.Attach(path);
//mapi.Logon(ParentForm.Handle);    //not really necessary
mapi.Send(subject, body, true);
```

Comment: The question is tagged HTML. As far as I have seen Mapi cannot be used from a web page. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234916/send-mail-using-default-webclient-in-asp-net-using-mapi-in-c-sharp-web-applicati

Comment: @DovMiller Yes, it will only work for desktop apps. If you really need to open outlook from a web app you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229240/javascript-open-outlook-and-add-attachments-to-new-email . But if all you need is to send an email the link you sent has a much better solution.

Answer (score -16):

what about this

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="mailto:jburns@htmlgoodies.com" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
Attachment: <INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="attachedfile" MAXLENGTH=50 ALLOW="text/*" >
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Email"/>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Tried it out on a jsfiddle... it just opens an email dialog and prefills the body with `attachedfile=filename.ext&submit=Email`.  It doesn't attach any data.

Comment: Works, The file referenced attach the file in the client