# How to attach files in Outlook using mailto in HTML?

Tags: html, email

I use the following code to send mail using Outlook:

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com?Subject=Hello%20test&body=Testing&attach=/Users/administrator/Desktop/test.txt">
Send Mail</a>
```

The problem is that I can't attach a file in Outlook. I have tried with 'Attachment' parameter but the same issue occurs. Can it be done or is there an alternative?

Comment: There is no way to do this through Outlook from a web browser, you should send the email from the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using mailto to send email with an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment)

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed. Mind the risk of attaching a local file just by clicking a link, an attacker may get sent any sensitive file on your disk!