# send a html email with attachment

Tags: html, web, email-attachments

I have to put a link on a web page where you open the mailbox with scitto everything and also Annex loaded. How can I do?

```
 <a href="mailto:email@echoecho.com?subject=SweetWords
    &body=Please send me a copy of your new program!">Email</a>
```

The file to attach is "Image.png"

Comment: maybe this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment-html-or-jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.You can not attach a file directly to a mail link. This will offer a challenge to security. To send a file you need to create a "file" field, Choose file, Upload it to server & then send.

Comment: isnt that still possible? Its actually a stupit thing if you think abou tit. It is not allowed to  add an attachmant and show the mail mask to the user, but its allowed to automatically send mails without the users knowledge (after he provides his username and passowrd)