# Open an email in the native iOS email application from a webpage

Tags: ios, web, email

I'd like to create an email "file" (i.e. stored on my webserver) that can be accessed through a link on a webpage and which will open the native iOS email program and have the To, CC, BCC, Subject and Body filled in.  Additionally I'd like the email to have an attachment.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the usage of `<a href="mailto:someone@somwehere.com">` then I'm afraid the answer is no. More details in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment-html-or-jsf).

This can be done, though it requires the use of PhoneGap/Cordova. This however, requires an iOS app containment. You can have the app communicate with your server. I'm assuming though, that you have a server hosted webapp and require this functionality.

If this is the case, the standard way to do this is to send the email on the server side. This of course, will not use the native iOS email application. If you don't have access to you own mail server, you can use a gmail account as an SMTP server. If your server is written in Java you can use [JavaMailSender](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html). If your server is written in Ruby, use the [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem. If your server is written in node, use [NodeMailer](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/nodemailer). Most popular languages will have a Mail Library suitable for you needs.