# Add an attachment to a email in c#

Tags: c#, email-attachments

How can I add an attachment to the mailto function in C#?

This is what I have so far:

```
 VWGClientContext.Current.Invoke("(function() {window.location.href='mailto:" + "myemail@outlook.com" + "?Subject=" + "SubjectText" + "&body=" + "BodyText" + "'; })();");
```

Is it something like this "&Attachment=" ....?

The file that needs to be added is stored on a server not a local pc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using mailto to send email with an attachment, html or jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment-html-or-jsf)

Comment: @bviale because the file commes from the server not from my local pc.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `mailto:` link.
Instead, send the email from the server using the classes provided in the `System.Net.Mail` namespace. This way you can add the file that's on your server as an attachment, using the [`Attachment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. (there is a code example in the MSDN page I've linked to)

If you need to, you can have the user fill out a form with the message body and subject and send the mail using the user input.

Answer (score 1):

you might be interested in this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
&attach=C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\username\Desktop\foldername\NameOfFile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

can use :

```
&attach=filename
```

Comment: It wont add the attachment file =/