# How to use mailto attachment in Angular.js

Tags: html, mailto

I want to add attachment path, how to add attachment in mailto.
I have tried like following but that not worked.

```
  $scope.sendMail = function () 
   {
        $scope.to = "To@gmail.com";           
        $scope.cc = "CC@gmail.com";
        $scope.bcc = "bcc@gmail.com";
        $scope.subject = "Confirmation";       

        var link = "mailto:" + $scope.to
                 + "?cc=" + $scope.cc
                 + "&bcc=" + $scope.bcc
                 + "&subject=" + $scope.subject
                 + "&body=" + "Test Body";
                +"&attachment=" 

        window.location.href = link;     
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using mailto to send email with an attachment, html or jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment-html-or-jsf)