# How to add attachments in an email using mailto: URI scheme for hybrid apps(in iOS)

Tags: html, cordova, web, html-email, email-attachments

I am trying send pictures and audio from my Cordova app as attachments in the mail using mailto: URI. For this, I am using URI similar to:

```
mailto:some.one@somewhere.co.il?subject=my%20report&body=see%20attachment&attachment=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/041193A7-DA1B-4B10-94B5-321FF380C85C/tmp/cdv_photo_003.jpg
```

The image uri is the path of the image I took using Cordova camera plugin in the same app, that was saved in documents directory.

But i do not see any attachments when the mail client opens. Is it because of sandboxing and restrictions by Apple? Is it even possible to send attachments from app directories in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

According to [using mailto to send email with an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment), it's not achievable via mailto.

But it's achievable in native iOS development via [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

Now that you are working with Cordova, you may need to look for Cordova's support for MFMailCompose or [a plugin like this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/blob/master/src/ios/APPEmailComposer.m)