# Open outlook attaach a file using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i want to open outlook and attach report to mail using react js from web application.
[image]

later user will enter receiver mail and cc.

I tried below code

```
window.location.href= 'mailto:'
```

please suggest any idea other then above code

Comment: Here have the same question as yours. you can refer it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778919/reactjs-send-email-with-email-body-and-attachment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJs - Send Email with email body and attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778919/reactjs-send-email-with-email-body-and-attachment)