# Have a Shiny App Populate an Email on the Client's Side

Tags: r, shiny, mailto, rdcomclient

I would like the Shiny app to allow users to prepare an email (which would be knit in html before sending) and then the app would open the user's Outlook with the email all ready, with attachments.

I can achieve this on my work computer using the `RDCOMClient` package, but the app would need to be deployed on the company's server, which runs on linux. In fact, there are no mailing software installed on the server, hence why the whole thing would need to be send to the user's default mailing software (which is Outlook for everyone).

I've had some success using the html `mailto` link, but it does not seem to allow for attachments nor html pre-formatted body.

There is a similar question here, but unfortunately it did not receive any reply: [Connecting Shiny App to local Microsoft Outlook Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593433/connecting-shiny-app-to-local-microsoft-outlook-account)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: not poosible using `mailto`, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment

Comment: I know, hence why I'm looking for an alternative :) just mentioned it to inform people that I've looked at that option.