# SharePoint 365 link Image to email template

Tags: image, sharepoint, office365, email

Everyone,

I am working on a Sharepoint 365 page and trying to use an image that will link to an email template.

On my page I have an image that is inserted into a content editor in a web part. I have set the image link to mailto:xyz@abd.com. this work great. It will open my default email program (outlook) new message ready to fill out and send.

What I am trying to do; is use the same image in the content editor and when people click on image an email still pops up to send a new email, but I want this new email message to be a specific email template (not a blank email).

Comment: Where is the email template stored? What have you tried? Post the code you have so far. Or don't you have any code? Then you're in the wrong site.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to predefine the message's body and subject in `mailto` links just by adding the query string to the link like this:

`mailto:example@example.com?subject=Test Subject&body=Test body`

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add any attachments, media ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment)), or any HTML to the message's template ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)). The `mailto` links always treat the message's body as a plain text.

More about mailto: [html mailto tips and tricks](http://www.angelfire.com/dc/html-webmaster/mailto.htm)