# How to open outlook from client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to open the outlook from client side.I use the code below and its working fine.The only issue is that not able to attach any document through this code.

```
    <a href="mailto:mailto@cxx.com?cc=mailcc@cxx.com&subject=hello&body=have a nice day!">send Using Outlook</a>
```

Please give your valuable suggestions

Comment: No you can't automatically attach documents by this method. But if you want to send an email why not just do it from the server side directly?

Comment: The requirement is that when a user select a document from our application and click on send button the document is shown in the outlook mail compose panel with document attached.

Comment: Well whoever wrote the requirements does not understand what is possible in a web based environment. You'll have to tell them to think again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using mailto to send email with an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment). The accepted answer at this link also contains suggestion for solving the problem

Comment: No problem. Hope you can agree a sensible requirement with your client which is also technically possible.