# How to send an attachment in mailto in angular

Tags: angular, mailto

I have generated a QR code from a .csv file and I want to share it via email in my angular app.

I am trying to send the data URL in the body.

Either attach the file using attachment or show the image in mail body using data URL.

Comment: Nope, this is not possible at all. There is no provision for it in the mailto: protocol, and it would be a gaping security hole if it were possible.

Comment: You can't add an attachment for security reasons. A base64 could probably work, but I don't think it would, and I have never tried it.

Comment: look at this article it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment

Comment: What if I upload the QR code on the server and send the image URL from the server in the mail?