# Sending mail with attachments in Angular 8

Tags: angular, email-attachments

I have been trying to send attachement with mail using angular8.
Tried following code
 `a href="mailto:youremail@email.com?attachment=<your filepath>"`
Path looked like this C://Inetpub/wwwroot/myfile.pdf
But, This just opens up an empty outlook without attachments.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/5233556/8355466

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, it is not possible to do so. Mail-To links are not supporting attachments.

Because what you're doing here, is you create a link, and because of the beginning 'mailto:' your browser knows that this should end with an e-mail. So it opens up your standard mailing app/programm, with a new mail to the given mail-address.
It's not sending the E-Mail, so there's also no way to get data from your server. If you really want to attach something to the e-mail from the server, you will need to send the mail via a Backend-Service (PHP, Java...). There are planty of libraries to make this easy.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The file is not from server but an exported .csv file that would be downloaded and sent along with email as an attachment from my local machine.

Comment: Without a backend there's no way to go i think... Do you use a backend already in your application?

Comment: Yes SQL Server and web api to fetch data.

Comment: You mean .net Web-Api? You could upload the csv-file to your API and send the e-mail from your backend. Then you can define one E-Mail adress, your application will send this mail + attachment from. I think this would be the best way to do it

Comment: But what if the email address to whom the attachment will be send is not defined or depends on user wish. Are you suggesting silent sending of emails?

Comment: You can always do some sort of Interface. For example you could ask your user, to whom the e-mail should be sent, with which text and transmit this information together with your attachment-file via http-call (put-method)