# Attach file to gmail using only Html and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to use `mailto:` protocol to attache a file

https://codepen.io/Su1312/pen/bGEQgKv

```
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
```

Comment: The question asks for a code snipplet to attach file to the body of the email. Thank you. If u give me a working snipplet, u will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Ok. So Javascript cant send attachments in email? Wow

Comment: No, the protocol doesn't allow to send the files and not JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to attach file via `mailto:` protocol.

The file is in the client computer and there is no way for a website to know which files are in the users hard disk.

Even if it knew, it would be a huge security threat that any random website can get to have an email sent with a file of choice in users computer.

Here is a related question: [using mailto to send email with an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment)