# Adding an attachment to default client mail service

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I run the following code, the client mail service opens up with the To:, Subject:, Body: except the attachment which is highly needed. I couldn't figure out why the attachment is not adding into the mail.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      
     final String HTML = "<h1>Hello</h1>"
        + "<p>This was created using iText</p>"
        + "<a href='hmkcode.com'>hmkcode.com</a>";

    String filePath = "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/pdfTest/a.txt";
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HTML, new FileOutputStream(filePath, true));

    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

    try {
        // Open user-default mai
        // l client application.
     
        String message = "mailto:username@domain.com?subject=New_Profile&body=see%20body%20content&attachment=" + filePath;
        URI uri = URI.create(message);
        desktop.mail(uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `desktop.mail();` twice? Shouldn't you just do `desktop.mail(uri);`?

Comment: sorry i removed it.. but still the same.. its not getting attached

Comment: Can you get the right behavior from your browser by pasting the URI you are generating into its address bar?  Do you know that the "mailto" URI spec and the target email client both support the specification of `attachment` in the way you are attempting?

Comment: isnt there is way to sent the attchment then.

Comment: thank you, isnt there is any other way to do. i wanna open clients default mail service with an attachment.. –

Answer (score 1):

According to [using mailto to send email with an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment) there is no support for attachments in mailto uri. And I, too, think that this is quite a logical behavior, for file access being extremly dangerous in a security point of view.

Comment: thank you, isnt there is any other way to do. i wanna open clients default mail service with an attachment..